# Using 'jms.useAsyncSend=true' for some messages and verfying it in the consumer side

Tags: glassfish, apache-camel, activemq-classic, fuseesb

We are using the embedded activemq broker within Fuse ESB (7.1.0) with consumers co-located .

The producer client is deployed on a remote GlassFish server. It uses activeMQ resource adapter (5.6.0) along with spring jms template. The client publish messages to different queues. I want some of the messages (going to a given queue) to use jms.useAsyncSend=true where as the other messages should use the default. I see below options

1) I can't append the the option 'jms.useAsyncSend=true' in the resource adapter URL because that will enforce it for all messages.

2) The JNDI look-up for the connection factory is returning an instance of 'org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQConnectionFactory'. I was actually expecting an instance of org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory, which would have allowed me to use setUseAsyncSend() for the corresponding jmsTemplate. So I can't use this option as well.

3) I have multiple connection factories configured under the GlassFish connectors (one for each queue). I am trying to pass the property 'jms.useAsyncSend=true' as an additional property to a particular connection factory. I am expecting this to be used only for the connections created in that particular connection pool. Now, having done this I want to verify if it really worked.

Question 1) Is there a way where I can check in the consumer side if the property 'useAsyncSend' was set in an inbound message? This is to verify what I have done at producer side has actually worked. Note that I am using camel-context to route messages to the end consumers. Is there a way to check this within the came-context? is there a header or any such thing corresponding to this?

Question 2) Is there a better way to set 'useAsyncSend' in the producer side where one resource adapter is used for sending messages to different queues with different values for 'useAsyncSend'.

I understand that 'useAsyncSend' is an activeMQ specific configuration hence not available in jmstemplate interface

Appreciate any help on this.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Fuse ESB, but I have created different ActiveMQ connections with different properties (in my case it was the RedeliveryPolicy). You then direct your producers and consumers to use the appropriate connection.

So, if using Spring xml to define your connections, it would look something like this:

```
<!-- Connection factory with useAsyncSend=true -->
<bean id="asyncCF" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${broker.url}" />
    <property name="useAsyncSend" value="true" />
</bean>
<!-- Connection factory with useAsyncSend=false -->
<bean id="syncCF" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${broker.url}" />
    <property name="useAsyncSend" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Or specify the useAsyncSend as a parameter on the url value.

This might help you with Question 2.